# How to add images via REST API to Magento 2 products in wysiwyg editor / description?

Tags: php, rest, magento2

I am using PHP and the REST V1 api for importing products to Magento 2. Everything is working, except for 1 thing: I need to show images in the description of the product. I can upload these images through the wysiwyg-editor in the Magento backend, but I want to do this via api.

I use this endpoint to add the main product images:
`rest/V1/products/:sku/media`

This works like a charm, but now I need to upload detail-images that I can use in the description. Using the endpoint mentioned above also adds the images to the main thumbnail list on the product page, and that's not what I want.

Is there a method to upload these images and get the image-urls in the response so I can use them inside the description attribute?

Comment: Did you ever find an answer to this?